# Check if form input fields have not changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form, let's call it `myForm` similar to this:

```
<form name="myForm" class="vertical grid-block shrink" ng-init="initSearch()" ng-submit="doSearch(myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
```

And three input fields: one with keeps details, second which is a starting date and third which is a ending date.

The fields look like this:

```
<input id="details" type="text" ng-model="myObject.details" placeholder="DETAILS_PLACEHOLDER">


<input id="from" class="uppercase" type="text" name="from" placeholder="{{datePlaceHolder}}" ng-model="myObject.from" required/>

<input id="until" class="uppercase" type="text" name="until" placeholder="{{datePlaceHolder}}" ng-model="myObject.until"/>
```

And I want to display a button based on the form fields. If the form fields have not changed the button should be hidden.

I tried using `$dirty` but the problem is `$dirty` remains `true` even if the user types in details and then deletes the text.
Anyone has any solution for this?

Also the solution must work even if I come back to the form from another page which probably has another controller.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This should fix that. It checks for $pristine, ie untouched.

```
<button ng-show="myForm.$pristine"></button>
```

Comment: The same problem as $dirty. $pristine keeps false value even if I type something and then I delete the text.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at sample below, basically you need `$viewValue` for displaying/hiding submit button.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myObject = {};
  $scope.datePlaceHolder = 'from date';
  $scope.datePlaceHolder2 = 'until date';
  $scope.doSearch = function() {
    alert('submit');
  }

  $scope.initSearch = function() {
    console.log('init search called');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <p>Need to fill FROM and UNTIL values to submit</p>
  <form name="myForm" ng-init="initSearch()" ng-submit="doSearch(myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    <input id="details" type="text" ng-model="myObject.details" placeholder="DETAILS_PLACEHOLDER">

    <input id="from" type="text" name="from" placeholder="{{datePlaceHolder}}" ng-model="myObject.from" required/>

    <input id="until" type="text" name="until" placeholder="{{datePlaceHolder2}}" ng-model="myObject.until" />

    <button type="submit" ng-show="myForm.from.$viewValue && myForm.until.$viewValue">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

You can add more conditions to

```
ng-show="myForm.from.$viewValue && myForm.until.$viewValue"
```

Notice that if you delete value from input, submit button disappears